# Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType /Custom model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a custom model for registration and want it to save all the form info into database. It worked when i used User model but User model is auto generated model and i don't want to rewrite it every time i decide to make changes. So now when i did this custom Register model inherit from User model i getting this error when i try to register new user.

here is my Register model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using CreckJackMVC;

namespace CreckJackMVC.Models
{

public  class Register : User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]//Important for auto User Increment
    new public decimal cj_user_id { get; protected set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please provide full name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    new public string cj_user_name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please provide your email", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})$",
                ErrorMessage = "please enter valid email")]
    new public string email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please provide password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "password must be 8 char long")]
    new public string user_pass { get; set; }

    [System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute("user_pass", ErrorMessage = "confirm password does not match")]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    new public string confirm_user_pass { get; set; }

}
}
```

here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Register(CreckJackMVC.Models.Register U)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (CreckJackLiveEntities dc = new CreckJackLiveEntities())
            {

                //you should check duplicate registration here 
                dc.Users.Add(U);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                U = null;
                ViewBag.Message = "Registration successful! Welcome to CreakJack! ";
            }
        }
        return View(U);
    }
```

here is error msg: 
[image]

Comment: I think you have to map it to `Register`, I don't know if you can inherit the mappings.

Comment: i don't have Register table, that is the deal i  have one User table but  i want to make multiple custom models from is so i can do different actions with it like Register or Login models you know.

Comment: So i don't know how  to map it to User table trough Register model if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `Register` model should not inherit from `User`. Instead you need a view model representing what you want to display/edit in the view (see also [What is viewmodel in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc))

```
public  class Register
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please provide full name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please provide your email")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "please enter valid email")]`
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please provide password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "password must be 8 char long")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [CompareAttribute("Password", ErrorMessage = "confirm password does not match")]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller

```
[HttpPost
public ActionResult Register(Register model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      return View(model);
    }
    User user = new User()
    {
      UserName = model.UserName,
      Password = model.Password
    }
    // Save the user
    // Redirect to another view (e.g. the home page) - NOT return the view
}
```

Side notes:

1. Using `AllowEmptyStrings = false` is unnecessary since `false` is
   the default value
2. Use `[EmailAddress]` rather than you custom regular expression (it
   will generate the correct regular expression)
   You will probably need additional checks to ensure the email does not already exist (and you can use a `[Remote]` attribute for client side validation
3. It would appear you are trying to just save the password in the
   database (in plain text), in which case this is dreadful practice.
   Passwords need to be hashed (and preferably salted) and the hashed
   value stored in the database
4. Strongly recommend you follow normal PascalCase naming conventions
   for your model properties

Comment: Thanks i got it now, i read more on mvc topic and i guess i can move from there